# How to display a message in echo-area only

Tags: echo-area, message

Is it possible to display a message in the echo area without logging it in buffer  `*Messages*`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Bind `message-log-max` to `nil`:

```el
(defun foo ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((message-log-max nil))
    (message "EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE")))

M-x foo RET
```

[P.S. Don't be misled by tests using things such as `M-: (let ((message-log-max nil)) (message "EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE"))` into thinking that the `EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE` *from evaluating the* `let` *sexp* is the message that was output by `message`. It is instead the value returned by that evaluation. `message` does not log anything to `*Messages*` if `message-log-max` is `nil`.]

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find a built in way to do it, so I hacked this weird function:

```
(defun echo-and-ignore-message-buffer (message)
  (let ((prev-msg-log-max message-log-max))
    (unwind-protect
        (progn (setq message-log-max nil)
               (message message))
      (setq message-log-max prev-msg-log-max))))
```

Check out the documentation for `message-log-max`.

Comment: Sorry Renan, Drew was the first to post the answer (less that 1 minute before you). Thank you for the answer :-)