# How to use the echo area to display useful information?

Tags: echo-area

Since the [echo area](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/The-Echo-Area.html) at the bottom of a frame is blank when the minibuffer is not active, I'd like to use it for something I don't always need but is informative (like showing `org`'s clocking, battery level etc).

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: To answer your question, yes it is possible. Can you frame your question in a different way? How exactly do you want to customize the echo area? The [`symon`](https://github.com/zk-phi/symon) package is an example that uses that area as a system monitor when emacs is in idle state.

Comment: You can also have a look at [eldoc](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/ElDoc), which also makes use of the echo area.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make use of an empty echo area to display information](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/7563/184) (which does not have an accepted answer as of today, and so does not qualify as a reason for closing).

Comment: @kaushalmodi I doubt the answer given in the dupe will "fully address" the OP's question, since it basically says that it is not possible. Since you apparently disagree, would you mind expanding your comment into an answer to the other question?

Comment: Apparently, `symon` uses the "spam non-logged messages" route, so it probably is less troublesome than I thought.

Comment: I closed this thread so that all answers would end up on the original -- that way we don't have to keep track of both.